# Slicing strings omits letters at end

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string `abcdefghi` and a distance 3, I'm splitting it in this manner:

```
st = 'abcdefghi'
substrings = []
for i in range(3): 
    substrings.append(st[::3])
    st = st[1:]
```

Which should ideally give me:

```
String 1: adg
String 2: beh
String 3: cfi
```

But instead, under my method, the last alphabet (or more if the string is longer) gets omitted ie. `String 3: cf`

How do I fix the corner case?

**EDIT:** The example string here is too small to reproduce the error. A much longer string would reproduce the error.

Comment: Uh, there's no "i" in the input string, so why would you expect to get "cfi" as output?

Comment: Oops, that was an error. Editing q

Comment: Well, now it's a no-repro. The result of that code is `['adg', 'beh', 'cfi']`.

Comment: I just rechecked, and the string here is too small to reproduce said error (I was using a longer one in my case off SO.) The top answer below fixed my issue though. Sorry for the amateur behaviour, please close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the offset index directly when slicing to avoid modifying the original string:

```
substrings = [st[i::3] for i in range(3)]

# ['adg', 'beh', 'cfi']
```

That said, I was unable to reproduce your error with the amended string using your loop approach.

Comment: This is StackOverflow, not CodeReview. The question wasn't "How can I improve this code?". Your answer is not actually an answer.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yep I also realised the no-repo *after* I wrote this answer. Will delete if you believe to be appropriate.